# How do I use FindSiteMapNodeFromKey(String)?

Tags: asp.net, sitemap, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm looking to get a set of child nodes from a sitemap starting at a specific node. I've looked at the Microsoft documentation but don't really know how to use it.

Can anybody provide me an example?

Comment: `MvcSiteMapProvider` doesn't seem to work, gives back `null`?

Comment: Can you post some more info? What's your sitemap looking like, what code are you using, ... Context is king :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you set the key on your mvcSiteMapNode, like this:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="My Action" action="MyAction" controller="MyController" key="1234" />
```

You can call FindSiteMapNodeFromKey() to get a reference to that node.

```
var node = MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.Current.FindSiteMapNodeFromKey("1234");
```